# Extra tag appearing when enter

Tags: jquery

```
    function limitofTags(){
    var tags = $('div').find('.tag').map(function(){
        if (!$(this) = '')
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    $("#tags").prop('disabled', tags.length >= 12);
    var limit = 12;
    var $counter = $('.numoftags');
    var remains = parseInt(limit - tags.length);

    if(remains == 1){
        $counter.text(remains + ' more tags');
    }

    if(tags.length >= limit){

        $counter.text('Cannot display anymore tags');
    }

    else{

        $counter.text('Add ' + remains + ' more tags');
    }

}
```

When saving the draft without entering tags, on next page, it will show the delete icon without text. I am trying to find why it is showing delete icon on next page when saving a draft without entering tags.

**EDIT #2**

```
function addTag() {
    // invoked on button click or spacebar
    var tag = $.trim( $('#tags').val() );

    if(tag !== ''){

        $('<div class="tag"><a href="" class="tag-delete"><i class="icn-delete"></i></a>' + tag + '</div>').appendTo('.tags-box');

        $('#tags').val('');
    }
    limitofTags();


}
```

It shouldn't add tag as above. But still it is showing empty tag with delete icon on next tag.

Any pointers or guide or help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method has more problems you need to test the text of the element not $(this), also trim it

```
var tags = $('div').find('.tag').map(function () {
    var text = $.trim($(this).text())
    if (text != '') {
        return text
    };
}).get();
```

Comment: I thought addTag function was the cause cos i tested without limittags and see if addTag function still added empty. hmm

Comment: still have a problem with empty tag showing up after submit. i think it doesn't relate to limit tag function.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
if (!$(this) = '')
```

should be

```
if ($(this) != '')
```

Comment: oops you are right, but still it shows the icon delete hmm. I am adding the function in edit above shortly